# reading CSV files and measuring time taken until loading is finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm kinda new in ReactJS and I've been working on a component that can load  a CSV file. 
At this moment this component is able to load a CSV file but I wanna measure how long it takes until this component has loaded a CSV file. So, I'm thinking about calling 'setInterval' method by calling it every seconds and when loading finished, I'll call clearInterval or something like that.
I have this concept but Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this and where to start.
Can anyone help me out here?

Here's my code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class CSVFileUploader extends Component {

componentDidMount() {

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
     document.getElementById("file").innerText = reader.result;
  });
  reader.readAsText(document.querySelector("input").files[0]);
});}

render() {

return (
  <div>
    <input type="file" />
    <button id="myBtn">Read it!</button>
    <pre id="file"></pre>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default CSVFileUploader;
```

thx in advance!!

Comment: You can use console.time and console.timeEnd()